# Issue using FBRequestConnection error handler for fetching Facebook data

Tags: iphone, facebook, error-handling, facebook-fql

For fetching all the friends details at a time,I have used FQL query and FBRequestConnection with error handler to save all the data in to an array i.e.

```
- (void)fetchFriendDetails
{
    NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,name,birthday_date,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"];

    // Set up the query parameter
    NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                query, @"q", nil];
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:queryParam
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (!error)
                              {
                                  NSArray *tempArray = [result valueForKey:@"data"]; 
                                  NSMutableArray *tempArrayAbout = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray]; 
                                  self.friendsDetailsArray = tempArrayAbout;
                                  NSLog(@"details are %@",friendsDetailsArray);
                              }
                          }];
}
```

When user clicks the sync button,the above method is performed and later on saving data in to db is executed. But I have an issue here! Since the FBRequestConnection error handler is a call back function what happens is it initially doesn't execute and for the 2nd attempt it enters and save all the friends data in **friendsDetailsArray** ,here is my sync button action:

```
- (IBAction)syncSettings:(id)sender
{
if (self.remindBeforeDaysField.text.length != 0 && self.setTimeField.text.length != 0)
    {
        self.syncProgressHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
        self.syncProgressHUD.labelText = kSyncingBirthdays;
        self.syncProgressHUD.detailsLabelText = kPleaseWait;
        self.syncProgressHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:syncProgressHUD];
        syncProgressHUD.delegate = self;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            // Do the task in the background
            [syncProgressHUD show:YES];
            [self saveUpdateFriendDetails];
            // Hide the HUD in the main thread 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Since I had an issue with friendsDetailsArray,I had to move my code to **viewDidLoad** method,which has worked well for me as far as saving data is concerned.I don't understand why I am unable to update data despite of the fact that I could see all the conditions,array values,the set which holds all the Facebook friend id's through logging.In other words I could save the friends details,but couldn't update it.

**To my surprise upon debugging I found out something crazy,I have retrieved all the Facebook friend id's(if existing) and stored in NSMutableSet,then checked the condition whether the set contains our Facebook friend id or not,I think if my database already holds the Friends records,then the condition should be valid,but shockingly it is not validating and jumping to vice-versa condition i.e. if set does not contain our Facebook id**,here is my sample implementation code:

```
-(void)saveUpdateFriendDetails
{
NSLog(@"reminder set values are %@",remindersSet);
NSLog(@"id is %@",facebookID);
if(updateIfExistSwitch.on && [remindersSet containsObject:facebookID])
{
   //Do update stuff
}

else if(![remindersSet containsObject:facebookID])
{
   //Do insertion stuff
}
}
```

Here is the logged output for clarification:

[image]

As we can observe in the image that my Facebook id is present in the NSMutableSet i.e. remindersSet,I don't know why the condition: **if(updateIfExistSwitch.on && [remindersSet containsObject:facebookID])** is not being validated :O

Also I believe writing the code in viewDidLoad is not at all the correct way to address the scenario as who knows,user might enter details and click sync button rapidly and by the time the syncing of friends details will not take place.I have tested the scenario too.I think all the stuff is revolving around one place,i.e. FBRquestConnection error handler as I could see through debugging that it doesn't enter the loop for the first time,but for the second time.

I want the fetching friends details action to be executed first and then later the saving/updation of data in to sqlite database.

**Note: saveUpdateFriendDetails is the method where I save or update data,you can observe the line [self saveUpdateFriendDetails] in sync button action**

Can any one please guide me?

Useful suggestions applauded,thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution finally,let me answer my own question so that some one might benefit out of it.Succeeded in solving 2 issues:

**-> [remindersSet containsObject:facebookID] condition fails because facebookID is retrieved in NSDecimal format,so we need to specify the string format before retrieving it.**

**-> Second issue being call back function,since it is a call back function,we need to perform our save or update operation after details are fetched and saved in to array.**

Hope this helps some one

Thanks :)